# source() functions preventing the read of downstream functions

Tags: r

I am trying to teach myself `R` and coming from a Python programming background.

I am clearly having problems with sourcing in one file (`file_read_functions.R`) when the functions stored in it are called from a file in the same directory (from `read_files.R`).

`file_read_functions` is as follows:

```
constant_source <- 'constants.R'
function_source <- 'file_read_functions.R'
class_source <- 'classes.R'

source(class_source)
source(constant_source)
source(function_source)

cellecta_counts = read_cellecta_counts(filepath = cell_counts_by_gene_id)
```

`file_read_functions.R` is as follows:

```
constants <- 'constants.R'
classes <- 'classes.R'
assignments <- 'assignment_functions.R'

source(constants)
source(classes)
source(assignments)

read_cellecta_counts = function(filepath) {
  print("hello")
  return(filepath)}
```

With the above, if I move `read_cellecta_counts` to before the `source` functions, the code can successfully find the function. What might be the cause?

Comment: What you've shown is the function definition. The error is from when you are calling the function which is presumably somewhere else. There are no additional error messages you can turn on. The message means at the time you are trying to call the function, it cannot be found. It's hard to give a more detailed message for something that R doesn't think exists. Look where you have the code that has the "cell_counts_by_gene_id" part in the error message. That's actually what's being called.

Comment: @MrFlick Hmm interesting. I had the same problem yesterday (to which you responded, thank you) and I think fixing the problem with the function was what resolved it. I updated the code above to show what calling the function entails.

Comment: Which of these files is the function defined in: `constant_source`, `function_source`, `class_source`? If you add `print(ls())` before the function call, that should print everything that's defined. Is the function listed there? Do you have any code that uses `rm()` in the other files you are sourcing? What if you just change the function to `read_cellecta_counts = function(filepath) {return(filepath})`. There's gotta be something going on in the parts you are not showing us.

Comment: @MrFlick The function is defined in `function_source`. I performed `print(ls())` and none of the functions from `function_source` are defined. This problem persists when I change the `read_cellecta_counts` to be as you suggested. Why would `R` not be able to find the function if it is in the same directory? Thank you so much for all of your help; you are a lifesaver.

Comment: What if you run `ls()` right after the source? If it's still not there, are you absolutely sure you have the correct file path?

Comment: @MrFlick That does not work either. I found, however, that it can find a function in the `file_read_functions.R` if the function precedes the `source` calls in the `file_read_functions.R` file. I tried re-writing the names that the I use the `source` function on but to no avail. Any thoughts as to what could be going wrong with the `source` functions in the `file_read_functions.R` file?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Please provide a reproducible example in your question. Show the exact names of files and what they contain. But make the example minimal. We don't need any of the actual logic of the function unless it's necessary to reproduce the error. If the function just `print("Hi")` but you get the error, that's sufficient to see what's going on.

Comment: FWIW `source("my_module.R")` is more or less equivalent to `from my_module import *` in Python ... if you forgot to import a module in Python you'd be having similar problems ... and `traceback()` could be useful.

Comment: There is at least one typo in the code you have posted here ( `for (i in starting_row_by_gene_id:`  ) do you see any warnings or error messages?

Comment: I edited the above to try and better fit the question to my current understanding of the problem. It seems like @BenBolker has a description that is closest to the issue. I still have had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a straight-forward error message to me. The function object wasn't found, so that means you haven't defined it anywhere, or haven't loaded it.

If it's a function from a package, maybe you forgot to load the package, or call the function as `package::function()`. If it is a function you wrote as a simple script, maybe you forgot to source it or define it locally. If it's a function you wrote as part of a package, you can load all functions by using the shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+L` in RStudio.

That said, I believe you can benefit a lot from reading the chapter on Debugging from Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R" book. It is really well written and easy to understand, especially for beginners in the R language. The chapter will teach you how to use some debugging tools, either interactively or not. You can find it [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html).

Comment: ... or the file you sourced has a syntax error in it somewhere which prevented the function from being defined ...

Comment: @BenBolker wouldn't that give an error during the function execution?

Comment: if they were running commands interactively (cutting and pasting) they might not have noticed that the `source()` failed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. By commenting out the parts piece-wise in `file_read_functions`, I found that there  a typo within `assignment_functions.R`. It was a simple typo; I had the following:

```
constant_source <- 'constants.R'
source(constants_source)
```

The extra 's' did it.

If you get an error like this in the future, be sure to check all of the upstream source() files; if there is an error in any of those it will not be able to find any proceeding functions.

Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: But if that were the case, you should have seen an error when you sourced the file. Were you really not seeing any errors at all?? Or were you just only looking at the last error and not the first? And the example you included in the question did not have this typo. A reproducible example should be tested to verify it returns the same error. If the reproducible example doesn't reproduce the problem, it's useless.